# Make global config available to react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My scenario is as follows:

I have a component `<PasswordInput>` that has a prop `hide` that toggles whether the input fields `type` is set to `text` or `password`.

Now I have several `products` defined that define for each product if that prop should be set to `true|false`.

```
/products
  /prodA
    config.js
  /prodB
    config.js
  /prodC
    config.js
```

Each of those `config.js` files would contain similar:

```
export default {
  FEATURES: {
    hidePasswordByDefault: true,
  }
}

// or 

export default {
  FEATURES: {
    hidePasswordByDefault: false,
  }
}
```

With a special webpack config I alias the current compiled product via `process.env` so one can include the current product config via

`import Product from "product/config"`

Then I could, in theory, import the config in parent component that renders the `<PasswordInput>` component:

```
import Product from "product/config"

const SignIn = (props) => (
  <div>
    <PasswordInput hide={Product.FEATURES.hidePasswordByDefault}/>
  </div>
)
export default SignIn
```

But that seems like bad style.

Another option would be to use React `context` to propagate it down from a root `<Product>` component. But usage of context is not recommended I understood.

The last option I could think of, would be to pass down the product via props from a root `Product` component. But how can I make sure the prop is passed down to very last child?

Another reason why I don't want to include the product config at component level is that it could very easily create circular references in my particular webpack config.

Comment: I would suggest just importing the module or using `context`. The `context` API might not be 100% stable, but it's sure to stick around since many popular libraries like `redux` [depend on it](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/src/components/connectAdvanced.js#L81). You can follow the way they use it which abstracts away `context` from your consumer code by using a `<Provider>` top-level component and `connect()` Higher Order Components down-stream. I don't think there's really a better way to do this.

Comment: When you say... "With a special webpack config I alias the current compiled product via process.env so one can include the current product config via `import Product from "product/config"` - how exactly are you doing this in the Webpack config?